# Return and echo

Tags: php, return, echo

What happens if i echo something before a return in a PHP function? An example of this is the following:

```
protected function getStockFromGarp($data) {
    echo $data." stock returned from call ".$url;            
    return $data; // Returning $data for future date
}

public function updateStock($sku) {
    $entry->this = getStockFromGarp($sku);
}
```

Which will be the `$entry->this` value when calling updateStock($var)?

Comment: Yeah, probably just like asking for tips instead of working.

Comment: I shortened the code, lets say it is a simple var for this example.

Comment: It's a bad idea IMHO to store data in an object variable called `this`.

Comment: You skipped a lot of things. Firstly you know that `$url` and `$entry` is out of scope, right?

Comment: I shortened the code for this question and for this example. Assume everything else is correct and vars are in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP will first do the echo and then return $data. Echo outputs data but does not stop PHP from rparsing.

Maybe this will make it more clear:

```
class Conversation
{
    public $knowledge = array();

    public function say($string)
    {
        // echo $string;
        return $string;
    }

    public function listen($string)
    {
        $this->knowledge[] = $string;
    }
}

$me = new Conversation();
$johnDoe = new Conversation();

$johnDoe->listen($me->say("I've got a secret"));
$me->listen($johnDoe->say("Tell me!"));
```

If you were to use echo, I would've said that I had a secret, but John Doe would never be able to hear me.

Comment: You mean the value of $data in my example will be assigned to the $entry->this var and the string im echoing will do nothing to the $entry->this?

Comment: Your echo will be outputted to the browser or console and then $data will be assigned to $entry->this, so indeed the echo will not do anything to $entry->this

Answer (score 0):

The result ($entry->this) is the same as without echo.

Comment: You mean the value of $data in my example will be assigned to the $entry->this var and the string im echoing will do nothing?

Comment: The string after echo will be echoed = send to the browser (if no output buffering is activated). Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Echo outputs data, it doesn't return data. Using echo won't skip the return clause. It in itself also doesn't edit data, so your `$data` variable wouldn't be altered, and would return exactly the same as when it was used as an argument.